# Forward emails to multiple destinations using SQL virtual aliases postfix

Tags: sql, postfix-mta

I'm setting up an email system at the moment, and I need emails to one address to go to about 5 other addresses. I want to do this with postfix virtual aliases (SQL not a file), but I can't seem to get it to go to multiple targets.

Any help appreciated

Comment: This would be better off on ServerFault

Comment: @Samadi Can't post there for 40 mins

Answer (score -1):

There is a very simple solution.
All you have to do is just add the below at "/etc/aliases"
I assumed the below.
one address (announced target address) = stackoverflow
5 other addresses = user1, user2, user3, user4, user5

[step 0] check if the below line is existed at your "/etc/postfix/main.cf" file.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

[step 1] modify alias file of the system, just add the below

```
stackoverflow: user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
```

[step 2] apply alias

```
$ newaliases
```

Note that "stackoverflow" can be both virtual username and actual one.
If it is aactual user and it also want to get origin email, just modify it as the below.

```
stackoverflow: stackoverflow, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
```

Comment: Hello, No, this doesn't work. My aliases are in a SQL table

Comment: In that case, you may want to change the "hash:/etc/aliases" part into your SQL table file at [step 0].